# Checking bash script argument doesn't work

Tags: bash, unix

I'm writing a bash script which runs other commands such as calling for yum to install a list of packages, and I'd like my script to silence the other commands by default, but let them output if I pass the -v argument. Issue I'm running into is that checking the value of $1 doesn't appear to be working correctly. Given the following code, my script will always echo "Yes":

```
if [[ "$1"=="-v" ]]; then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

If I just echo $1 and pass the script the -v, it echos -v as it should. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
Found it. Kept playing with the script and changed the first line to this:

```
if [[ $1 == "-v" ]]; then
```

Works now?

Comment: The version without spaces is always true: when a single argument is given inside `[[ ]]`, if that argument is non-empty then `[[` returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some spaces around your check:
`if [[ "$1" == "-v" ]]; then`

Comment: Thanks! I could have sworn I tried adding the spaces already and it hadn't worked, but like I mentioned in my edit, it's working with that change. I shoulda gotten that extra hour of sleep last night.

Comment: My answer and your edit must have passed each other on submit. Glad you worked it out! Don't forget that you can post an answer you find and accept it.

Comment: I'll try to remember that next time. :P Still waiting for it to let me accept yours.